# algorithm for largest island in a given matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, depth-first-search

Given a 2 X 2 matrix, return different island sizes that is possible

For example, the following matrix should return `[5, 7]`.

```
  1 0 0 0 1
  1 1 1 1 1
  0 0 0 0 0
  1 1 1 1 1
```

This is fairly straightforward problem. I am using a boolean visited matrix of same size and traverse the matrix in DFS fashion. I have implemented it here. for some reason, I am getting output as `[1]`. I tried debugging but my mind stopped working now. I am missing something silly I believe.

```
public class IslandConnectedCell {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] input = {
                {1,0,0,0,1},
                {1,1,1,1,1},
                {0,0,0,0,0},
                {1,1,0,1,1}
        };

        dfsIsland(input);

    }


    public static void dfsIsland(int[][] input) {
        int rows = input.length;
        int cols = input[0].length;
        List<Integer> countList = new ArrayList<>();

        boolean visited[][] = new boolean[rows][cols];

        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < cols; cols++) {
                if (input[row][col] == 1 && !visited[row][col]) {
                    int count = mark(row, col, input, visited, rows, cols, 0);
                    countList.add(count);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(countList);

    }

    public static int mark(int row, int col, int[][] input, boolean[][] visited, int rows, int cols, int count) {

        if (row >= rows || row < 0 || col >= cols || col < 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (input[row][col] == 0 || visited[row][col]) {
            return 0;
        }

        visited[row][col] = true;
        count+=1;

        for (int i = row - 1; i <= row + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = col - 1; j <= col + 1; j++) {
                if (i != row || j != col) {
                    mark(i, j, input, visited, rows, cols, count);
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why is the expected output for your example `[4, 7]`?

Comment: One obvious problem in `dfsIsland()` is at least that `for (int col = 0; col < cols; cols++)` should probably be `for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)` instead (maybe even better to use the common `i` and `j` for the row/col indices).

Comment: The code seems to define an "island" as neighboring 1's, in which case I see one island of size 7, and two islands of size 2. --- Or is this supposed to be a [wraparound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wraparound_(video_games)) world? If so, why can't I see any wraparound logic in the code?

Comment: yes, you are right. I edited the input matrix. I had a typo when I copied and pasted

Comment: Now it should be 5 and 7?

Comment: @MickMnemonic yep, thats right. edited again :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two errors in your code.

See [comment by Mick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51333342/algorithm-for-largest-island-in-a-given-matrix#comment89642389_51333342) for first error:

> One obvious problem in `dfsIsland()` is at least that `for (int col = 0; col < cols; cols++)` should probably be `for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)` instead (maybe even better to use the common `i` and `j` for the row/col indices).

Second error is your use of `count` in the `mark` method, most glaringly the lack of using the return value in the recursive call. Remember, Java is pass-by-value.
*Hint:* I suggest you remove `count` as a parameter.

Once you fix the errors, output will be:

`[7, 2, 2]`

---

```
public class IslandConnectedCell {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        int[][] board = { {1,0,0,0,1},
                          {1,1,1,1,1},
                          {0,0,0,0,0},
                          {1,1,0,1,1} };
        System.out.println(new IslandConnectedCell(board).getIslandSizes());
    }

    private final int[][] board;
    private final int rows;
    private final int cols;

    public IslandConnectedCell(int[][] board) {
        this.board = board;
        this.rows = board.length;
        this.cols = board[0].length;
    }

    public List<Integer> getIslandSizes() {
        boolean visited[][] = new boolean[this.rows][this.cols];
        List<Integer> countList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int row = 0; row < this.rows; row++)
            for (int col = 0; col < this.cols; col++)
                if (this.board[row][col] == 1 && ! visited[row][col])
                    countList.add(mark(row, col, visited));
        return countList;
    }

    private int mark(int row, int col, boolean[][] visited) {
        if (row >= this.rows || row < 0 || col >= this.cols || col < 0 || this.board[row][col] == 0 || visited[row][col])
            return 0;
        visited[row][col] = true;
        int count = 1;
        for (int r = -1; r <= 1; r++)
            for (int c = -1; c <= 1; c++)
                if (r != 0 || c != 0)
                    count += mark(row + r, col + c, visited);
        return count;
    }

}
```

---

**UPDATE**

To get the desired output of `[7, 4]` ([original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51333342/1)), the board would need to use horizontal wraparound, so the two small islands on the bottom line becomes a single larger island.

That is easily accomplished by modifying one line of code to wraparound the column index using the `%` modulus operator:

```
count += mark(row + r, (col + c + this.cols) % this.cols, visited);
```

Comment: Neat solution. Thanks for catching the mistake on pass by value.